# iOS - Add NSDictinary key values into an NSArray sequencialy

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` and a `NSArray`:

```
self.dataDic = [[[NSDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
self.dataDicKey = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

These are the key and value of my `NSDictionary`:

```
    self.dataDic =
    @{@"Ring Cloud" :@[@"Contact Cloud", @"Image Cloud", @"Data Cloud"],
      @"Ring Tools" :@[@"Sticker Market", @"Live Poll", @"Mail"],
      @"Ring Apps"  :@[@"Studio", @"Player"]};
```

Now what I want is to insert all the **key** value of my `self.dataDic` into `self.dataDicKey` sequentially. That means it looks like this:

`self.dataDicKey = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ring Cloud", @"Ring Tools", @"Ring Apps",nil] autorelease];`

I have tried with this:

`self.imageDicKey = [[[self.imageDic allKeys] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`

But it's not actually sorted the values. If any one have any suggestion please share it with me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what you are trying to achive? I could not understand your question

Comment: as per my knowledge is allKeys mehtod return only NSArray of keys. regardless of order

Comment: you could try to save with some tags and later sort them accordingly

Comment: You can even try NSPredicate also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get the `keys` as `objects` in your `NSArray` you should try this method

```
self.DataDicKey = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.imageDic allKeys]];
```

One thing to remember that `NSDictionary` allKeys method returns only the keys regardless of order they were saved. as its `KVP`

This will copy your `NSDictionary` keys into `NSArray`

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` keys are unsorted - maybe you could save the keys in array before you enter the data to the dictionary