# Sort/Filter dictionary by property of object in Key

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary, custom-properties

I have a dictionary like 
eg:

```
let dict = Dictionary<Month, Array<Int32>>()

Obj1.price = "10"
Obj1.value = "abc"
Obj1.title = "January"

Obj2.price = "10"
Obj2.value = "def"
Obj2.title = "April"

Obj3.price = "10"
Obj3.value = "pqr"
Obj3.title = "February"

Obj4.price = "4"
Obj4.value = "mnq"
Obj4.title = "April"

dict = [ Obj1: [3,4], Obj2 : [1,2], Obj3: [8,9], Obj4: [3,3] ]
```

I have a custom array of month

```
let sortTemplate = ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March"]
```

I want to get the dictionary sorted as 
[ Obj2 : [1,2], Obj4: [3,3], Obj1: [3,4], Obj3: [8,9] ]

In short I am expecting to sort the dictionary according to custom reference array on property of key.
I know we cannot have sorted dictionary but want to sort according to custom sortTemplate and insert into Array of dictionaries

Any hint in this regard will be useful.
I know we can sort with values and also keys

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749219/ios-add-nsdictinary-key-values-into-an-nsarray-sequencialy/30749359#30749359

Comment: @SyedAliSalman why? He does not want Keys of a dictionary in an array. He just wants them sorted. Is it because of your comment about Dictionaries being unsorted in Objective-C? I think in Swift they can sort dictionaries.

Comment: Do you `Month` class conform to protocol `Hashable`?

Comment: Edited the question, I want keys sorted according to sortTemplate and insert the dictionary into Array of dictionaries so that they can be remain in sorted order.

Comment: @dfri: I have added override var hashValue: Int function, which return the hash value of title, value and price

Comment: @NSNoob well, i am not confident about it.

Comment: @nkp u can try `dict.sort { $0.1[1] < $1.1[1] }` then print it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution which uses `Dictionary`s built-in sort function, however presenting the `title` property in your example as custom `enum` rather than a `String`. The "sort template" is then given implicitly by the ordering of the months in the `enum`.

I.e., `enum MonthSortTemplate` and your class `MyClass` (the latter which you have not shower us, so I made a MWE myself) as:

```
enum MonthSortTemplate: Int {
    case April = 1
    case January
    case February
    // ... rest of months follows, in the order you prefer
}

class MyClass {
    var price = ""
    var value = ""
    var title: MonthSortTemplate = .April    
}

// Hashable (just some dummy, don't know how you've set this up)
extension MyClass: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return price.hashValue ^ value.hashValue
    }
}

// Equatable (just some dummy, don't know how you've set this up)
func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.price == rhs.price && lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

Create your `MyClass` instances, add into your dictionary, and use `.sort(...)` function of the latter for a custom closure, specified for this specific type of comparison.

```
var Obj1 = MyClass()
var Obj2 = MyClass()
var Obj3 = MyClass()

Obj1.price = "10"
Obj1.value = "abc"
Obj1.title = .January

Obj2.price = "10"
Obj2.value = "def"
Obj2.title = .April

Obj3.price = "10"
Obj3.value = "pqr"
Obj3.title = .February

var dict = Dictionary<MyClass, Array<Int32>>()
dict = [ Obj1: [3,4], Obj2 : [1,2], Obj3: [8,9]]

// your custom sort closure, for Dictionary.sort(...) method
let byMonthTemplate = {
    (elem1:(key: MyClass, val: [Int32]), elem2:(key: MyClass, val: [Int32]))->Bool in
    if elem1.key.title.rawValue < elem2.key.title.rawValue {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

let sortedDict = dict.sort(byMonthTemplate)
print("\(dict)")
```

---

An alternative---if your really like your class property `title` to be of type `String`---is to define the `<` operator for `MyClass` objects:

```
func <(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    // do comparison stuff with strings lhs.title and rhs.title
    // with regard to your ordering of choice (array sortTemplate)
    return ... 
}
```

In this case, the "messy" stuff ends up in this function, whereas the actual sorting can be performed quite elegantly as

```
let sortedDict = dict.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

Personally, I would prefer the `enum` solution (that, however, is off topic).

---

EDIT:

At your request, I'll include one example of the `<` operator for your class `MyClass`. This is by no means an optimal one, but perhaps you can refine it from my example.

```
// add sortTemplate as a static property of MyClass
class MyClass {
    var price = ""
    var value = ""
    var title = "" 
    static let sortTemplate = ["April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March"]
}

// define < operator for MyClass objects
func <(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
    let indexOfLhs = MyClass.sortTemplate.indexOf({$0 == lhs.title})
    let indexOfRhs = MyClass.sortTemplate.indexOf({$0 == rhs.title})
    return indexOfLhs < indexOfRhs
}

// you can now sort your dictionary according to
let sortedDict = dict.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

Comment: Enum is certainly a nice and great solution, but I would have to change a lot of code at this moment. Can you suggest something in String. How we will write func < to compare from sortTemplate. If unable to find anything, I will implement the Enum method

Comment: is the sortTemplate fixed? I.e., is this template valid for all your MyClass() object?

Comment: plus i am using the title for displaying in UI as section headers

Comment: yes sortTemplate is fixed, which I am receiving from API

Comment: Then: could it be appropriate to let the `sortTemplate` be a static member of `MyClass`? I've added an suggestion for the "string solution" where this applies.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help, quick and dirty way

```
let dict = ["Obj1":[3,4],"Obj2":[1,2],"Obj3":[8,9],"Obj4":[3,3]]

let dict1 =  dict.sort { $0.1[0] < $1.1[0]} //Sort by first object in array
let dict2 =  dict1.sort { $0.1[1] < $1.1[1]} //Sort by second object in array

print(dict2)
```

Out put:`[("Obj2", [1, 2]), ("Obj4", [3, 3]), ("Obj1", [3, 4]), ("Obj3", [8, 9])]`

Comment: this would sort with regard to the 1st/2nd integer entry in the Int32 array, but the poster wants to sort w.r.t. his custom month sort template, comparing the member property `title` in his `MyClass` objects against this template.

Comment: convert to month string is really easy also, just use another dict with `num:month` or enum or even localized string and  convert based on that